# Phonegap parse external HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

I'm wrinting on a PhoneGap app that has the HTML and Javascript for the Navigation local and it should load the contend from the Web.

I don't have direct controll over the content Server so I can't change anything there.

The Content i want to get in to my app is based on a normal HTML website so i want to get for example the Text in da div or so.

What i have so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var url = "http://example.org/"
  updateGadget();

  inervalID = setInterval("updateGadget();", 60 * 1000);

  function updateGadget() {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax(url, {}, function (response, status, xml) {
            console.log(response);
        });
    });
  }
</script>
```

The Problem is thad it doesn't work, it shows me nothing.

For developing is use a Webserver not directly PhoneGap. When i open the Website in Google Chrome it shows the error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://example.org Origin http://example.org is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

in the Console.

I found the i should use this header:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

Where should i use it, if i put it in my HTML (PHP) file to the Top it does nothing an on the Server i want to Parse I cant put it.

Where is the Problem, and how can if fix thad?
Or is there a better Way to do this?
If possible i want to di it directly on the PhoneGap app without a secound server backend.

Comment: You must [whitelist all domains you use](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html) in your PhoneGap application.

Comment: @apsillers at the Moment i  run the website und a webserver for testing and not on PhoneGap.
Is there a Way to do it then?

Comment: The site that is *offering the page* must serve `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`. This is a way for the server to say "yes, I will allow browsers to use this page cross-origin." If you don't control the website, you don't have the ability to say whether browsers can use it cross-domain or not. Perhaps you could try using a proxy like http://whateverorigin.org/, or [disable your browser's adherence to the same-origin policy](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3102819/710446) (but note that this should be done during testing *only* -- it's unsafe to leave this disabled during normal browsing).

Comment: I agree with apsillers. Moreover, using a server-side scripting (e.g. php) allows you to cache (e.g. APC) your parsed contents and improve response time.

Comment: See what error code you get... use  $.ajax({

    url: 'http://example.org/',
    data: myData,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'jsonp', //whatever is your data type
    success: function() { alert("Success"); },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {    alert('Failed!' + textStatus); }
});

Answer (score 1):

This [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15005500/loading-cross-domain-html-page-with-jquery-ajax) question has a solution for you.

Basic idea is to make `$.get` request at `http://whateverorigin.org/get?url=webpage-you-wish-to-scrap.com`