# If select box on site updates, notify me?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, real-time

I'm trying to get notified when a site updates stock of a certain product. The site has a select box with a list of items, this list gets items added randomly during the week.

Is it possible to do the following?
-check select list on website every x minutes
-if list has changed since last check do this.

If someone could guide me into what i need to research and look at, that would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, my preferred way is using some Server-Side language such as PHP/Java and make a HTTP-Request and then parse the page and find the requested select/element.

You've tagged this question as javascript/jquery so I'm guessing you're aiming to this kind of solution.

It's possible. You'll need to make a **cross-domain** request and parse the results to get the select box value.

Take a look at this question for how to make a cross domain request:

[Loading cross domain endpoint with jQuery AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15005500/loading-cross-domain-html-page-with-jquery-ajax)

take a look at jQuery API to parse and traverse HTML.

the rest is basically case-specific programming

Comment: Ok great! There doesn't seem to be a readme or tutorial for it. How do i go about actually using the files from git?

Comment: Okay that was easy haha! I've managed to parse with YQL. I've come across an issue however. The site im trying to parse has 5 items in the drop down list. It does not display the items not in stock. However, when i parse the data. I seem to get back all 20 drop down items, even though only 5 are displaying on the actual site(the ones in stock). Any idea why this is happening?. if i do an inspect element on the drop down box, it only shows the 5 items.

Comment: They probably have some js that removes the unstocked items after page is loaded.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49317/discussion-between-shay-elkayam-and-namenone)