# AJAX - Cross-domain don't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cross-domain

I was reading many things about that the json is great replacement for XMLHttpRequests. I tried it and it don't works:

```
$.ajax({
crossDomain: true,
    url: settingsURL,
type: "POST",
dataType: 'JSONP',
parseAsHtml: true, cli: 'help',
    success: function(data) {
        data=$(data).find('div#TestDivContent');
        $('#TestDivContent').append(data);
    },
error: function() {
        $('#TestDivContent').append("<p>Can't Connect</p>");
    }
});
```

and im getting...

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

Comment: The above error means the server response is not JSONP but HTML (or XML).

Comment: I quitly know what's it caused by. Just need a solution. I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: If you can't edit the server side code, let's change the dataType as 'text'.

Comment: If i change it i get XMLHttpRequest error

Comment: JSON is not a replacement for XMLHttpRequests, they are different things. This post is related to your question:
**[Loading cross domain html page with jQuery AJAX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15005500/loading-cross-domain-html-page-with-jquery-ajax/17299796#17299796)** – _the last one, supports https_

Answer (score 0):

Please Check the code below that is working like a charm in Cross Domain (). 
if You Have control of both the Domains i.e., Domain1.com & Domain2.com

```
//Ajax Script in Domain1.com
//No Conflict is the code snippet from my sample code You can delete it if not required no issues
<script type="text/javascript">jq1102 = jQuery.noConflict( true );</script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
    function jsonp(n){
        //GET Response is Here
        alert(n);
    }

    jq1102(function(){
        jq1102.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            url: 'http://domain2.com/ClientSiteApi/',
            crossDomain: true,
            complete: function(data){
                //Any Action You Like to Trigger After Complete 
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, ex) {
                //Nothing to Change Here
            }
        });
    })
</script>
```

Response from Domain2.com

```
 echo 'jsonp("hello")'; //You Can place JSON string in replace of the Hello String
```