# Accessing different page controls using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I access different page controls using `JavaScript`?

For example, I have two pages: `Page1.htm` and `Page2.htm`.
I write my JavaScript code in `Page1.htm` and I need to access a textbox or any other control which is placed in `Page2.htm`.

Comment: Please show some effort and show what you tried. This is not a ask and get the code forum.

Comment: @RonniSkansing : Thanks for your reply. I don't have any specific code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like,

```
$(function(){
    $.get('page2.html',function(html){
       console.log($(html).find('textarea'));
    });
});
```

Comment: How can I achieve if the pages are in different domain. I am getting the following error.
access-control-allow-origin' header is present on the requested resource. origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access

Comment: You should refer [loading-cross-domain-html-page-with-jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17299796/1817690)