# How do I load a page using ajax, query, json?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, json

How can I load a page using jQuery, AJAX, and JSON? I've tried something like this, but it is not working.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">

<div id="wsww">content.<div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$.get('https://www.google.com/')
 .success(function(data) {
     $('#wsww').html(data);
 });
</script>
```

Comment: You can't do that. Its a cross domain access.

Comment: so theres now way to display data from a different website, because istead of using an iframe i was thinking on using this

Comment: Sure there is a way, just not with clientside ajax that violates the same-origin policy

Comment: im not trying to get the content from is a diff website other than google, whats a good idea to use ?

Comment: A serverside language comes to mind ?

Comment: **I wrote an answer for this question here:
[Loading cross domain html page with jQuery AJAX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15005500/loading-cross-domain-html-page-with-jquery-ajax/17299796#17299796)**

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the .success function, instead use a callback function...  try this

```
$.get("<url>", function(data){
  $('#www').html(data);
});
```

Comment: **I wrote an answer for this question here:
[Loading cross domain html page with jQuery AJAX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15005500/loading-cross-domain-html-page-with-jquery-ajax/17299796#17299796)**

Answer (score 0):

[Cross Domain Access](http://jsfiddle.net/JrSs8/1/)

### HTML

```
<div id="Content">

</div>
```

### Jquery

```
$.getJSON('http://whateverorigin.org/get?url=' + 
          encodeURIComponent('http://google.com') + '&callback=?',
          function(data){

            $("#Content").html(data.contents);
});
```

### Reference

[Whateverorigin.org/](http://whateverorigin.org/)