# How to get some page by url in javascript

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, cors, postman

I want to get page from web-site using javascript.
I have url like:

```
http://not-my-site.com/random
```

From 'random' I will be redirected to another (random) page on the web-site.
Postman do everything like I want :) It's get whole page (html). But how can I do the same from javascript?
I tried CORS alredy following this guide http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/ but without success. I still just get an error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://not-my-site.com/random. 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Code from tutorial:

```
function createCORSRequest(method, url) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {

    // Check if the XMLHttpRequest object has a "withCredentials" property.
    // "withCredentials" only exists on XMLHTTPRequest2 objects.
    xhr.open(method, url, true);

  } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {

    // Otherwise, check if XDomainRequest.
    // XDomainRequest only exists in IE, and is IE's way of making CORS requests.
    xhr = new XDomainRequest();
    xhr.open(method, url);

  } else {

    // Otherwise, CORS is not supported by the browser.
    xhr = null;

  }
  return xhr;
}

var xhr = createCORSRequest('GET', 'http://not-my-site.com/random');
if (!xhr) {
  throw new Error('CORS not supported');
}

xhr.onload = function() {
 var responseText = xhr.responseText;
 console.log(responseText);
 // process the response.
};

xhr.onerror = function() {
  console.log('There was an error!');
};

xhr.send();
```

And also I tried common xhr like this (got the same error):

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'http://not-my-site.com/random', true);
xhr.send();
```

Comment: Could you please post the code giving you this error ? (extra bonus if it's a MCVE)

Comment: there's nothing to try about cors; either the remote site implements it and it works or it doesn't, and there's nothing you can do except use a server-side proxy or a service like YQL in the later case...

Comment: Finally, I used Whatever Origin. Works fine...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15005500/loading-cross-domain-html-page-with-jquery-ajax

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a problem of CORS not being configured correctly on the server. The below PHP code should allow any request from any domain. (If you're not using PHP, it should be easy to convert the below code into any other language, the clue is to write to the HTTP header).

Remember to place this code *before* any HTML is outputted.

```
$origin=isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])?$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']:$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '.$origin);        
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, OPTIONS, GET, PUT');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, X-Requested-With');
header('P3P: CP="NON DSP LAW CUR ADM DEV TAI PSA PSD HIS OUR DEL IND UNI PUR COM NAV INT DEM CNT STA POL HEA PRE LOC IVD SAM IVA OTC"');
header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1');
```

Accepting requests from all domains is insecure. For a better (but slightly more complex) solution, see here: [CORS That Works In IE, Firefox, Chrome And Safari](https://404it.no/en/blog/cors_that_works_in_ie_firefox_chrome_and_safari)