# Mimic Curl Headers in Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, curl

I'm trying to mimic this curl command to an ajax call.

```
curl -H 'X-Auth-Id' 'someid' http://someurl.com/api/posts
```

I've tried using

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://someurl.com/api/posts',
    type: 'get',
    headers: {
        'X-User-Id': userId
    },
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

But I seem to be getting an Invalid status code error, which I do not get when using curl from bash.

Comment: See [Loading cross domain html page with jQuery AJAX -- jQuery Ajax Notes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15005500/loading-cross-domain-html-page-with-jquery-ajax/17299796#17299796). 

**cURL** is a command line tool for getting or sending files using URL syntax and it is not affected by the **same origin policy**, by the other hand, due to browser security restrictions, most Ajax requests are subject to the same origin policy;