# How to load cross domain html using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, load, cross-domain

I have 2 different java web projects running on 2 different tomcat server.
Lets say projA and projB
Here I am trying to load html available in projB from projA. I am simply using jQuery.load() to achieve this.But it is giving me No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource error. I also tried to use jquery cross domain plugin availabele here https://github.com/padolsey-archive/jquery.fn/tree/master/cross-domain-ajax

But this does not work out.
Any help will be appreciated.

code i am trying

```
$191('.ontop').load("http://"+host+":8080/OtherDomain/",function(response,status) 
{

    if (status == "error") 
    {
        $191('.ontop').empty();
        var msg = "Sorry We could not connect to our server.. Please try again later.";
        alert(msg);
    }
    else
    {
        alert(status);
        $191('.ontop').css('display', 'block');
    }
});
```

Comment: Did you try a jsonp request?

Comment: basically i am not calling any backend API. Its just a loading HTML located at different domain.

Comment: Its an security feature of browsers. You can call an function on your projA and then call projB from there using CURL or any other server side method.

Comment: $( "#result" ).load( "www.google.com" ); does this work?

Comment: @KNeerajLal  yes it does work 
but not with my localhost :(

Comment: response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); add this to your webpage.

Comment: @KNeerajLal i already added that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is the answer for CORS error i am getting:

I added following filter in my web.xml

```
 <filter>   
      <filter-name>myResponseFilter</filter-name>
      <filter-class>com.filters.ResponseHeaderFilter</filter-class>
      <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    </filter>


    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>myResponseFilter</filter-name>     
        <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

and then there is a custom Filter written to set headers:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse httpResp = (HttpServletResponse) response;      

        String origin = httpRequest.getHeader("origin");
        origin = (origin == null) ? "*" : origin;

        httpResp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin);
        httpResp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST");
        httpResp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        httpResp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with, Content-Type");
        httpResp.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "86400");

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use a proxy server to request it.

I found [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15005500/loading-cross-domain-html-page-with-jquery-ajax/%22Here) and made this fiddle- http://jsfiddle.net/2kn52u3s/1

**code snippet-**

setup ajax headers-

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    scriptCharset: "utf-8", //maybe "ISO-8859-1"
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
});
```

And then request a cross domain JSON Request as-

```
$.getJSON('http://whateverorigin.org/get?url=' + 
    encodeURIComponent('http://google.com') + '&callback=?',
    function(data) {
      $("#target").html(data.contents);
});
```

Comment: Hi manoz, I just tried that fiddle and there i replaced encodeURIComponent('http://google.com') with my URL as below
encodeURIComponent('localhost:8080/OtherDomain') but it does not display content in div

Comment: yes it does work with live domain such as facebook
But what if i want to display html at localhost

Comment: @user3300140, Basically this encodes the url in utf-8 format and hence the header is set to the same encoding, So browser would allow request of encoded url(s). And if you are trying at local machine I guess there shouldn't be any cross domain error?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain?rq=1 this might help

Comment: @user3300140, Please put your code in the question.

Comment: @Manoz code added , $191 is nothing but a jQuery substitute variable

Comment: @Manoz http://whateverorigin.org/get?url gives me service unavailable error. Error code 503

Comment: @user3300140, Because you are passing blank parameters to it. Here is the url you all need to know about- http://www.whateverorigin.org/

Comment: $.getJSON('http://whateverorigin.org/get?url=' + 
    encodeURIComponent('http://localhost:8080/OtherDomain/') + '&callback=?',
    function(data) {
      $("#target").html(data.contents);
});

I used same snippet but it says service unavailable

Comment: @Manoz i just replaced www.google.com with localhost:8080/OtherDomain