# jQuery plugin for international phone numbers: flags and phone placeholder missing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, contentplaceholder

I'm using [intl-tel-input](https://github.com/Bluefieldscom/intl-tel-input), jQuery plugin for international phone numbers, for one of my projects. The plugin claims to "Automatically set the input placeholder to an example number for the selected country", but I can't get that to work properly. So far I tried 2 things:

1) I downloaded the library and referenced one of its JS files from my code ( similar to [the demo](https://github.com/Bluefieldscom/intl-tel-input/blob/master/demo.html)). Here's a snippet of my JS file:

```
  $("#phone").intlTelInput({
    allowExtensions: false,
    autoFormat: true,
    autoHideDialCode: false,
    autoPlaceholder: true,
    defaultCountry: "ng",
    ipinfoToken: "yolo",
    nationalMode: true,
    numberType: "MOBILE",
    onlyCountries: ['ng', 'us', 'gb'],
    preferredCountries: [],
    utilsScript: "/projects/intl-tel-input-master/lib/libphonenumber/build/utils.js" 
  });
```

but I got the following error in the JS console of Chrome:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///projects/intl-tel-input-master/lib/libphonenumber/build/utils.js. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

2) I put the library folder on a server and referenced utils.js file with server url (http://web.mit.edu/aizhan/www/intl-tel-input-master/lib/libphonenumber/build/utils.js). This still doesn't work on my machine, but it works in codepen with HTTP protocol but not with HTPPS:

HTTP: http://codepen.io/atoregozh/pen/raEPbv
HTTPS: https://codepen.io/atoregozh/pen/MYMLXv

My overall question: how could I make the library work locally? I also have 2 subquestions: 1) How to fix the error about XMLHttpRequest loading? (I read about it before from other posts on stackoverflow and I don't want to mess with the security settings); 2) Why the code works through HTTP but not through HTTPS?

I would really appreciate your help. If you want to see the actual project code, [the index.html file is here](https://github.com/kesiena115/HackDartmouth/blob/master/index.html) and [Javascript file is here](https://github.com/kesiena115/HackDartmouth/blob/master/js/hack-dartmouth.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**question**:how could I make the library work locally?

you use in [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) , ExpressJs or IIS Express.

e.g(run server): 
yeoman server

I'm test by IIS Express , demo file is right.

**question** :How to fix the error about XMLHttpRequest loading?

you load resource in another server (cross domain ), I prefer load proxy in curent server.
To resolve this problem, refer to ['Loading cross domain html page with jQuery AJAX'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15005500/loading-cross-domain-html-page-with-jquery-ajax).

**another question** :Why the code works through HTTP but not through HTTPS?

if you see the browser console , including the code below.

```
Loading mixed (insecure) display content "" on a secure page.
Blocked loading mixed active content "http://web.mit.edu/aizhan/www/intl-tel-input-master/build/js/intlTelInput.js"
```

resolve your problem in firefox [link](https://blog.mozilla.org/tanvi/2013/04/10/mixed-content-blocking-enabled-in-firefox-23/)

> if an HTTPS page includes HTTP content, the HTTP portion can be read or modified by attackers, even though the main page is served over HTTPS.

good luck.

Comment: also '[What is JSONP all about](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about)'

Comment: one can directly load from CDN as provided on their github documentation