# jQuery AJAX - JSONP convert text to JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

[Expected Duplication 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about)

[Expected Duplication 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15005500/loading-cross-domain-html-page-with-jquery-ajax)

I am searching a proper explanation about JSONP in various question but still not able to find.

For example,

I wanted to do a cross domain request using `JSONP` and the format of the response is `text/plain`. Is there any way to override or re-format the response? i.e. parsing the `text/plain` response with `dataType: "jsonp"`

I always get the error,

`Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/plain: "Some_url"`
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

Can someone explain me that the RestAPI should always return JSON formatted result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wanted to do a cross domain request using JSONP and the format of the response is text/plain.

You need to understand that JSONP technique utilizes `<script>` tag to load resource. Response should be valid javascript code then, which looks something like this:

```
callback_function({"some": "data", "in": "JSON format"});
```

So the answer to your question is no, you can't respond with HTML and then transform it, it will just generate the error you have already seen.