# How to make AJAX GET request on the client to external site with React

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, get, reactjs

Hello I'm new to React and I am trying to make an AJAX GET request to an external API. However, the URL I add is being prepended with my host. Please let me know if I am doing something off. Below is my code.

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'http://www.someapi.com/?i='+someId,
  async: false,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
    this.setState({data: data});
  }.bind(this),
  error: function(e) {
     console.log('error', e);
  }
});
```

The GET request is being sent to `localhost:3000/http://www.someapi.com/?i=1`

Comment: Never use `async: false`.

Comment: Because it freezes the browser/tab while the request is loading. You really need to learn to use asynchronous callbacks properly if you're going to do web frontend.

Comment: I don't want the user to do anything else prior to data being loaded. For this case it would be alright wouldn't it?

Comment: No. It's universally not alright. If you don't want the user to do anything before the data is loaded, hide or disable the relevant UI until it's loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are trying get `json` from a different domain there are security concerns, so the default behavior doesn't allow it, but you could use [`jsonp`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) as a work around.

Below is the modified version of your GET request that incorporates `jsonp`. The addition is specifying `jsonp` return type and a callback function name.

```
    // If you are doing making this request multiple times the AJAX request
    // may fail due to the same callback name, so you could generate random    
    // callback names to get around it.
    var callback = 'c'+Math.floor((Math.random()*100000000)+1);

    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: 'http://www.someapi.com/?i='+id,
      jsonpCallback: callback, //specify callback name
      contentType: 'application/json',
      dataType: 'jsonp', //specify jsonp
      success: function(data) {
        this.setState({data: data});
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(e) {
         console.log('error', e);
      }
    });
```

Comment: Glad I could help! Also look into [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) as a more secure way.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out these answers about cross-domain requests.

[jQuery AJAX cross domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain)

[Loading cross domain endpoint with jQuery AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15005500/loading-cross-domain-html-page-with-jquery-ajax/17299796#17299796)

It may lead you to the correct answer.