# Cross-Origin Request Blocked in Mozilla and ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE in chrome

Tags: cross-domain

This is my angular JS code. It was working fine few days back but now I get errors mentioned below.

AngularJS code:

```
app.controller("LoginCtrl",
        function($scope, $http,$location,$rootScope) {
    $scope.login = function(user){
        $http({
            method: "POST",
            url: "https://aadvq11nwbv01.staples.com/wcs/resources/v1/member/login?storeId=10101&responseFormat=json",
            header: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*",
            header: "Content-Type: application/json",
            header: "Accept: application/json",
            data:{
                companyID: $scope.user.customerid,
                userID: $scope.user.userid,
                password: $scope.user.password
            }
        })
        .success(function (response){
            $rootScope.profile="xxx";
            userDetails = response;
            console.log(userDetails);
            $location.url("/profile")
        })
        .error(function (err){
            $scope.logerr="err";
        });
    }
});
```

Chrome error:

```
https://aadvq11nwbv01.staples.com/wcs/resources/v1/member/login?storeId=10101&responseFormat=json net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE
```

Mozilla error:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://aadvq11nwbv01.staples.com/wcs/resources/v1/member/login?storeId=10101&responseFormat=json. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17299796/5195629

Comment: Nothing seems to be working

Comment: Are you making a cross-origin request? What have you tried?

Comment: I tried one of the proxies and I also tried to whatever origin solution mentioned on the page