# Boostrap 3 Modal + jQuery with "whois script"

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I had this working at some point but it sttoped working and I can't figure out why.

Once I click button, modal will open with text loading... and nothing else is happening. I was able to see whois data for selected domain.
This is what I should be able to see in modal: http://demo.whmcs.com/whois.php?domain=test.info

Code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Domain Checker</title>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function viewWhois(domain) {
    jQuery("#modalWhoisLoader").removeClass('hidden').show();
    jQuery("#modalWhoisBody").hide();
    jQuery("#whoisDomainName").html(domain);
    jQuery("#modalWhois").modal('show');
    jQuery.post("http://demo.whmcs.com/whois.php", "domain=" + domain,
        function(data) {
            jQuery("#modalWhoisBody").html(data);
            jQuery("#modalWhoisLoader").hide();
            jQuery("#modalWhoisBody").show();
        });
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button type="button" onclick="viewWhois('test.info')" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">WHOIS</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="modalWhois">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="modalWhoisTitle">
                    WHOIS Results for <span id="whoisDomainName"></span>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body text-center hidden" id="modalWhoisLoader">
                <p><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Loading...</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="modalWhoisBody">
                            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
                                            Close Window
                                    </button>
                            </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

EDIT:

This is the correct code I'm using (I used `http://demo.whmcs.com/whois.php` only for purpose of this question):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function viewWhois(domain) {
    jQuery("#modalWhoisLoader").removeClass('hidden').show();
    jQuery("#modalWhoisBody").hide();
    jQuery("#whoisDomainName").html(domain);
    jQuery("#modalWhois").modal('show');
    jQuery.post("whois.php", "domain=" + domain,
        function(data) {
            jQuery("#modalWhoisBody").html(data);
            jQuery("#modalWhoisLoader").hide();
            jQuery("#modalWhoisBody").show();
        });
}
</script>
```

Comment: Why `jQuery.post("http://demo.whmcs.com/whois.php", "domain=" + domain,` gives no error, output or anything.  I'm sure that somwhere I've made silly mistake as this was working before.

Answer (score 0):

If you look the Developer Tools of your browser you should see that, after opening the modal, you get a

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://demo.whmcs.com/whois.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Basically, you are not allowed to call that URL because it does not accept cross domain requests (see here: [Loading cross domain endpoint with jQuery AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15005500/loading-cross-domain-html-page-with-jquery-ajax) ) .

When requesting a same domain resource, your example should work. Do you have a (non) working example?