# Cant pull data from JSON array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, getjson, steam-web-api

Currently I am trying to pull data from my steam inventory using the following link: http://steamcommunity.com/id/STEAMID/inventory/json/730/2. Using the link I can see the results in browser however when I actually try to pull the json with $.getJSON I simply cant figure out how to get it to work. Here is a simplified version of the code.

```
<script>
  $( document ).ready(function() {
    var items = {"rgIventory" : "4932985723947"};
    var url = "http://steamcommunity.com/id/STEAMIDHERE/inventory/json/730/2";
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
      document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML=data.rgInventory;
    });
    // document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML=items.rgIventory;
  });
</script>
```

This is just a simple project im trying to do, I want to eventually list everything in a nice table with the items according image. I just cant figure out how to pull in the JSON. Sorry for the stupid question I've just been working on this for a day now and can't wrap my head around it.

Thank you all in advance.

EDIT: Can someone post an example of what I need to do? Very confused.

Comment: Is it being executed from the same origin, i.e. `http://steamcommunity.com`?

Comment: Are you sure that this API allows CORS requests? Do you have any errors in browser console?

Comment: @unconnected I never even thought to look at the console, this is the wrrow I am getting. "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://steamcommunity.com/id/STEAMIDHERE/inventory/json/730/2. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access." Is there a fix for this or and I just doing something wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Loading cross domain html page with jQuery AJAX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15005500/loading-cross-domain-html-page-with-jquery-ajax)

Comment: @unconnected basically what should I do to get around this?

Comment: Unless the server supports JSONP, not much.

Comment: https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API/Feedback#API_Considerations_for_Web_Developers

Comment: Error : {"success":false,"Error":"This profile is private."}

Comment: I can't see any other way but to proxy requests through your server. So ajax requests local url, and server side requests steam and returns results back to the client.

Comment: Is there another way that is possible maybe without JSON?

Answer (score -1):

Try using json. Example given below

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',        
    url: '//steamcommunity.com/id/STEAMIDHERE/inventory/json/730/2',

    async: false,
    jsonp: "callback",
    jsonpCallback: 'someCallBackFunction',
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'jsonp',

    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        //do your stuff
    },
    error: function (e) {
        console.log(e);            
    }
});
```

Comment: The Steam Web API does not support JSONP