# Not able to resolve No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cross-domain, cors

I am trying to load the html from a url to a div container on my webpage but I am getting this error "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access."

My website is built using only html and jquery/javascript.

```
$('.myContainer').load('http://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/myfolder/mypage.html')
```

Please let me know how can I resolve this error?

Comment: You cannot make a "cross-domain" call to load a URL. There are solutions described here eg. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15005500/loading-cross-domain-html-page-with-ajax

Answer (score 2):

The page you are trying to load has this header in its response.

`X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN` which means, other domains except for its own, can not load this URL.

`X-Frame-Options` is used to restrict cross-domain resource accessing.