# Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at url

Tags: php, angularjs, web-applications, cross-domain, httprequest

It's the very famous browser error. I know it has been discussed a lot but I've noticed is a very generic error so I want to present my problem.

I am making simple requests (get,post) on a server where I have access. My browsers (chrome, firefox) give me `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at url (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' does not match 'null').` error.

When I use some of (hacking)plugins I get the responses fine.

What I've tried is to add on my back-end (on server):

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

in `index.php` file with no luck. Any other ideas ?

Answer (score 6):

Try adding

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, GET, POST");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
```

Comment: No luck... Am I missing something as regards the file where I should put the headers ?

Comment: Just add to your main php file

Comment: that's the index.php file

Comment: I've had this problem as well. The way I solve it is to have your request made to a file "in" your own domain, and in turn, that file does a `curl` request (in PHP) to the site/page/server that you need data from.

Comment: If you are making this request via AJAX from an HTML or PHP page, you would likely be calling the cross-domain URL directly. -- Now my approach, you create a new php file (call it `fetch.php` if you like).  The AJAX url will now be "fetch.php".  On the page `fetch.php` you instantiate a `curl` request to the cross-domain URL you were trying to reach.  PHP Curl requests are typically not blocked the same way as AJAX requests in terms of cross-domain.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this issue.

1. In your config.php add www pre in your domain.com
   exa.

**// HTTP**

```
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://domain name with www/');
```

**// HTTPS**

```
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'http://domain name with www/');
```

2. Add you htaccess file

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this. One way is the javascript way, which requires a callback and one example can be found here: [Loading cross domain html page with AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15005500/loading-cross-domain-html-page-with-ajax/17299796)

Another way is to utilize PHP's `curl` functionality.  Of course there are many ways to do this, but one method that works well for me is to:

- Create a standalone php page (can call it "fetch.php" if you
  like) that has 1 job.  That job is to make a curl request to a given
  URL (your cross-domain url in this case) and echo the data that it
  gets from the remote site.
- Change the AJAX URL from the cross-domain
  URL to the name of file created in previous step.
- AJAX then knows
  it's making an HTTP request to a location inside its current domain even though it's getting its data from a cross-domain location.

Hope this helps,
Adam

Answer (score 0):

You can whitelist the blocked URL like:

script-src 'unsafe-inline' https: 'nonce-abcdefg' 'strict-dynamic'

Answer (score -2):

I tried adding a chrome plugin "Allow-Control-Allow-Origin" after several tries with server side changes. Everything worked fine.

Comment: I know but the point is not to use plugins... So all users can have access