# Calling PHP on another server from Javascript, and waiting for it to complete

Tags: php, html, javascript

I have a PHP script on my server that needs to be run from my clients websites using Javascript in a plain HTML page. After the script is run the HTML page will redirect. The problem is that sometimes the script doesn't run before the redirect happens.

This is the code I am using...

```
$.ajax({
     async: false,
     type: 'GET',
     url: 'the_URL_of_the_PHP_on_my_server.php',
     success: function(data) {
     }
});

window.location="the_URL_for_the_redirect";
```

The PHP script on my server is to track hits/sales etc. Is there are way I can force the page to wait for the script to complete before the page redirect.

The HTML page and the PHP page are on different servers. Also, the HTML page is being used on lots of different websites, so I can't give them all permission to access my server. I'm not sure if that's causing a problem or not.

I don't need any information back from the PHP script I just need it to run.

Thank you.

Comment: if you want to redirect when request success, then put the redirect on success section

Answer (score 4):

The success function runs when you get a response (unless it was an error, in which case the error function you haven't defined would run).

If you want some code to run after you get a response, put it inside those functions instead immediately after the code which *sends* the request.

---

That said: The point of Ajax is to talk to the server *without* leaving the page. If you are going to go to a different page as soon as you have a response, then don't use Ajax. Use a regular link or form submission and then having an HTTP redirect as the response.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal, that this situation happens.

because `$.ajax` is async and won't wait till success method

change your code to

```
$.ajax({
     async: false,
     type: 'GET',
     url: 'the_URL_of_the_PHP_on_my_server.php',
     complete: function(data) {
          window.location="the_URL_for_the_redirect";
     }
});
```

---

**UPDATED**

changed function success to complete
difference is => 
complete will be called not matters what happened with request

---

**UPDATE 2**

think about @Quentin variant by html redirects.

Comment: Thank you. I'm changing this now, I'll test and let you know how it goes

Comment: @SteveHall yes, you have. But this is a problem with request from one website to antoher. So you should think about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery

Comment: I tried this change but it gives me the following error...
 
XMLHttpRequest cannot load PHP_PAGE. Origin HTML_PAGE is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Both pages are on different servers, so could this be the problem. Is there a way around this. I don't need any data back from the PHP script to the HTML page, I just need the script to run.

Comment: The PHP script is on my server, and I need to allow it to be triggered from my customers websites. Their websites are just plain HTML. Is this possible? My customers are complete newbies that just copy and paste the code I provide into their page.

Comment: @SteveHall try the code from answer ( changed success to complete ) + grant this request on your side => https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery

Comment: I've changed the code over, I have no idea how to grant the request. I read through the link you posted but it doesn't make sense to me. That's all way above my level of understanding. I am guessing I need to add some code to the PHP page to allow it to be triggered from a different server?

Comment: @SteveHall check if JS code works first. What kind of server do you use?

Comment: The code seems to work fine. The PHP page is to track hits and sales and if I refresh the HTML page (after deleting cookies) it does add to the tracking so it does trigger the code. But it returns the error and then won't do the redirect. It's a shared server running on linux, using cpanel.

Comment: @SteveHall add to your php code on start :
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http ://client.site.com");

Comment: please read answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15005500/loading-cross-domain-html-page-with-ajax/17299796#17299796

Comment: Thanks! That seems to be what I needed :) I just tried it with header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); and it works fine, but I guess this isn't a very secure thing to do! There are hundreds of client sites all on different servers that would need to run this script so I imagine having all of the domain names on a database and using an include on the php script would be the best way to do this?

Comment: @SteveHall kind of :)