# Get Title and Description for a URL with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making a web app to save bookmarks. I have a quick add feature that adds the URL to the favourites and collects the Title and Description for the site. So far I've got this:

```
var url = "http://google.co.uk";
var title = "";
var description = "";

$.get(url, function(data) {
  description = $(data).find('meta[name=adescription]').attr("content");
  title = $(data).find(title).text();
});
```

Unfortunately, this code does not work. Please help me fix it :). Thanks

Comment: You might find this information helpful:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has some typos:

1. $get should be $.get - [documentation here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)
2. running the corrected code may still throw some errors in the console. 
   The errors are related to cross origin restrictions.

Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15005500/loading-cross-domain-html-page-with-ajax) that explains the problem.

I hope this helps.