# Cross domain API call - locally hosted library

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, cross-domain

I need to get **HTML** from third party service. For this there are a number solutions mentioned at below stack overflow thread which are very easy to setup and work as well.

[Loading cross domain endpoint with jQuery AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15005500/loading-cross-domain-html-page-with-ajax)

I only see one problem which is hosting up/down time. For this I want to host it in my local folder let's say in `http://aamirshahzad.net/proxy/proxy.js`.

I have found one them can be hosted via node.js server etc but my limitation is I can just keep a JavaScript/HTML files on the server and access. Can't do any installations stuff or no server side stuff.

Any help here?