# How to load an external HTML file

Tags: javascript, html

I have some HTML as follows:

```
Select a file : <input type="file"><br><br>
Html Codes : <textarea id="displayHtml"></textarea><br><br>
<div id="displayPage">Display the Html Page here</div>
```

Now how would I browse an external HTML file from a local hard drive and display the page preview in the div `#displayPage` and get the HTML tags of the file into the textarea `#displayHtml`? I have no idea how to do this so please help.

My fiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/zm6ga2ev/1/

Comment: did you try appending the loaded html ?

Comment: To access a file from a file input, you need to upload it first or be allowed to use the [file api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/File)

Comment: @mplungjan any example

Comment: Not how SO works. Please do research and show effort. Start with the link I gave if you do not want to upload. If you want to upload search for access file after upload

Answer (score 2):

Let the user upload the html file into your server .

Here is a nice way to upload files via ajax : http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/uploading-files-with-ajax--net-21077

Now , you can use this code to load html file into the div tag

```
document.getElementById("displayPage").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="page.html" ></object>';
```

Or simply use jquery [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function

```
$("#displayPage").load("page.html");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using the File API within HTML5.

Here's a quick & dirty JS example:

```
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
  var file = evt.target.files[0]; // File inputs are an array - get the first element
  var reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onload = function(e) {
    // Render the supplied file
    document.getElementById('displayHtml').value = e.target.result
    document.getElementById('displayPage').innerHTML = e.target.result;
  };

  // Read in the HTML file.
  reader.readAsText(file);
};

document.getElementById('fileInput').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8te1hyv9/

A decent explanation and more comprehensive examples of how everything fits together can be found at: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Comment: @user5384372 in my opinion, this should be the accepted answer:  this answer includes examples and links to external sources.  the original question did not specify any external libraries and this answer does not use any.  plus, this answer comes with a complete working example in the jsfiddle link.

Answer (score 0):

You just [`.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) other page content into your div.

```
//Load full document
$('#displayPage').load('http://same-domain.com/next-page.html');

// You can use any CSS selector to load only part of page
$('#displayPage').load('http://same-domain.com/next-page.html #some-inner-id > *');
```

If `#displayPage` element is not found in DOM, than no request will be performed! If `#some-inner-id` is not found in request page DOM, than you get empty content.

---

*Note*

Loaded page must allow Cross-Origin request (usually it means same domain request). Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15005500/loading-cross-domain-html-page-with-ajax) for Cross-Origin requests.