# ajax request parsing: SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Tags: json, ajax

I make an ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/?method=getQuote&format=json&lang=en&jsoncallback=?",
    dataType: 'json'
});
```

and get an error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

When I click on that error in dev tools I see such an object which looks pretty ok for me:

```
{
    "quoteText":"Reality leaves a lot to the imagination. ",
    "quoteAuthor":"John Lennon",
    "senderName":"",
    "senderLink":"", 
    "quoteLink":"http://forismatic.com/en/9dceb1ebf1/"
}
```

Where is the problem? I'm unable to find the solution.

Comment: The URL you've provided is **not** a JSONP service yet you're trying to use it as one (via the `jsoncallback=?` parameter). It is also not set up for cross-origin requests so you'll have to use a proxy.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loading cross domain html page with AJAX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15005500/loading-cross-domain-html-page-with-ajax)

Answer (score 0):

Putting a `=?` in a URL overrides the `dataType` and tells jQuery to make a JSONP request instead of an XHR request.

The URL you are requesting returns JSON, not JSONP, so you get an error.

Remove `&jsoncallback=?` from the URL.

You will then get this error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/?method=getQuote&format=json&lang=en&js. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

… which is explained [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35553666/19068).