# IFrame with inline source (data:text/html...) gives a cross-domain error

Tags: iframe

I'm currently making an Iframe using javascript but when I try to access the iFrame using `myIframe.contentWindow.document` I receive the following error:

`DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:8082" from accessing a cross-origin frame.`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot edit the contents of an iframe for security purposes. It seems like you might be trying to set content in the iframe since the cross-origin error is being thrown. You can copy the contents of the iframe to another object then edit it.

Things to consider if this is true...

Use AJAX via jQuery.. [How to copy iframe content to div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40769161/how-to-copy-iframe-content-to-div)

If using Chrome, understand that Chrome does not support local CORS... [Deadly CORS when http://localhost is the origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10883211/deadly-cors-when-http-localhost-is-the-origin)