# Use google trends on my website via ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to display [google trends](https://www.google.com/trends/topcharts) on a website I am working on. I know that I can use iframes to display each individual trend, but I would like to display all of the trends. I cannot display the whole website with an iframe (not just because this error `net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT` but also because it would be plagiarism).

I am now trying to use ajax to achieve this but for some reason it is not working. I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15005500/loading-cross-domain-html-page-with-ajax) very helpful post, however I was not able to make any of their suggestions work. Here is the code I am working on so far (from the above post):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$.ajaxPrefilter( function (options) {
  if (options.crossDomain && jQuery.support.cors) {
    var http = (window.location.protocol === 'http:' ? 'http:' : 'https:');
    options.url = http + '//cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/' + options.url;
  }
});

$.get(
    'https://www.google.com/trends/topcharts#vm=cat&geo=US&date=201611&cid',
    //When I replace the trends URL with the example URL ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing ) Everything works perfect.
    function (response) {
        console.log("> ", response);
        $("#getOutput").html(response);
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="getOutput">loading...</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-trends-api  looks like their is an api for google trends

Comment: Is there a way to make that static?

Comment: Actually never mind. I am going to use browserify.

Comment: That is a helpful link, but not exactly what I am looking for. I would really like to get the ajax part working. thanks anyway