# Getting cross-origin error

Tags: cross-domain

I am trying to make following ajax request:

```
                                    $.ajax({
                                    method: "GET",
                                    url: http://google.com,
                                    dataType: "json",
                                    async: false,
                                    cache: false,
                                    success: function(data) {
                                    alert("AJAX call successfully 
                                    completed");}});
```

But as expected, I am getting "Cross-Origin" error. Is there any way to bypass this security and make the ajax call without this error even if ajax call is being made from different domain.

Any response is appreciated.

Comment: yes, using proxy server. Create a server/api in your domain and make your request to that server, the server will get cross domain data and send you back

Comment: Without alternations to the server you're trying to query (which I presume isn't Google) - no. You could see if JSONP requests are handled by them, else you're out of luck unless you can get them to open up the cross domain policies. The suggestion by @PriyeshKumar would probably work - but feels horribly underhand.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loading cross domain endpoint with jQuery AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15005500/loading-cross-domain-endpoint-with-jquery-ajax)

Comment: @thebluefox right,!. Making small api will take hardly 25 lines ^_^

Comment: @PriyeshKumar - I didn't say that it was hard, or would create lots of code. I said it was underhand - in the way that if a site does not offer an API, and does not allow Cross Domain Requests - then it's obvious they don't want their service used in that way.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a browser plugin that will allow you to request any site with ajax from any source

Chrome example:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi

Comment: how can you force your user to install it ?

Comment: You can make an html error message, that will tell the user to install it ;)

Comment: and if they don't ?

Comment: then javascript will throw the "Cross-Origin" error as expected

Comment: fair enough. your solution works for desktop users. What about mobile users?

Comment: yeah, that would be a problem, because mobile browsers dont support plugins (except for firefox on android) as far as i know.