# How to read a remote file with JQuery (and get a jqXHR readable error)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqxhr

I'm trying to read a remote file ; I'm using [the example on the jquery.get() documentation page](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) :

```js
    var jqxhr = $.get( 'http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/question/10943544', function() {
                       alert( 'success' );
                       })
    .done(function() {
                  alert( 'second success' );
                  })
    .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                  // alert( 'error' );
                  console.log('Error: (' + errorThrown + ')');
    })
    .always(function() {
    alert( 'finished' );
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

But it only triggers "fail" and "always" and I'd like to understand why ; My question is : **How can I obtain a readable error?** Currently, the `console.log("Error: (" + errorThrown + ')');` only yields `Error: ()`.

Bonus question: **Why does it fail?** How can I read a remote (RSS) file using JS/JQuery?

Comment: `textStatus` <-- Did you look at that?

Comment: It depends on the error. Not all error information is readable by the time it reaches your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is one of the **[Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)**, which is present on most AJAX requests, and put in place as a security measure. If you look at `jqXHR()` you can see that `readyState` is `0`, indicating this. Note that `readyState` will always be `0` when the request has failed, be it for policy restriction or a malformed request. The `error` message is blank because the restrictions are preventing the error message itself from triggering.

```js
var jqxhr = $.get("http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/question/10943544", function(res) {
    alert("success");
  })
  .done(function() {
    alert("second success");
  })
  .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    // alert( "error" );
    console.log("Error: (" + errorThrown + ')');
  })
  .always(function(jqXHR) {
    console.log(jqXHR);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

To get around this, there are a number of plugins, which are listed in [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17299796/2341603). It also states:

> The best way to overcome this problem, is by creating your own proxy in the back-end, so that your proxy will point to the services in other domains, because in the back-end not exists the same origin policy restriction.

However, assuming you can't do that, the easiest way is to make use of **[CORS Anywhere proxy](https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/)**, as is shown in the following snippet (note that the result takes a while to come through):

```js
$.ajaxPrefilter(function(options) {
  if (options.crossDomain && jQuery.support.cors) {
    var http = (window.location.protocol === 'http:' ? 'http:' : 'https:');
    options.url = http + '//cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/' + options.url;
    //options.url = "http://cors.corsproxy.io/url=" + options.url;
  }
});

$.get(
  'http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/question/10943544',
  function(response) {
    console.log("> ", response);
    $("#viewer").html(response);
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Don't really see why this is deserving of a down-vote? Keen to know to improve the answer.

Comment: I don't think it's clear enough on answering the question. *"My question is : **How can I obtain a readable error?** "* You did mention that the readystate would be 0, but, how does that translate to the given code? what else could result in a textstatus of 0? i mean, besides the fact that the actual error message is inaccessible via javascript due to the very reason an error is occuring.

Comment: Well you would get a `readyState` of `0` in any situation where the page is not ready to complete the request, such as a malformed or failed request. If you can't make the request, there is **no** way to get the error that I'm aware of outside of `errorThrown` (or completely re-crafting the request), as the error can't be triggered. I've updated the answer to cover this.