# Upload and send a file through jsonp request to cross domain

Tags: javascript, jsonp

I have to upload a file using input tag `<input type="file">` and send the file or file content through to other domain(cross domain).Can i make use  of `javascript jsonp` request to send file to a cross domain ?
It is mandatory to use pure javascript not `jquery` or `angularjs`

Is jsonp is the best method to send data(file object/file content) to a cross domain?

Here is my code

```
<input type='file' id='files' name='myfiles'/>

function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object
    console.log(files)
    var s = document.createElement("script");
    s.src = "http://192.168.100.115:8700/is_selected/";
    document.body.appendChild(s);

  }

  document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

Comment: provide your code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loading cross-domain endpoint with jQuery AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15005500/loading-cross-domain-endpoint-with-jquery-ajax)

Comment: I have added the code @Dipakchavda

Comment: jsonp is not the best option, it's now consider dangerous, and it's only possible with get requests. [Cors enabled](https://enable-cors.org/) ajax is the way to go if you want to send files using post