# VueJS PDF web view

Tags: vue.js, pdf, vuejs2

Hi I am trying to add a **pdf** web view to my vue js vuetify project.
I choose vue-pdf https://github.com/FranckFreiburger/vue-pdf for that.

My pdf src is directly come as a URL and code is like this.

```
<template>
  <pdf src="https://lovezwl.vip/pdf.pdf"></pdf>
</template>

<script>
import pdf from 'vue-pdf'

export default {
  components: {
    pdf
  }
}
```

Then I got an error

> Access to fetch at 'https://lovezwl.vip/pdf.pdf' from origin
>   'http://localhost:8083' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
>   mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

As far as I know CORS is something to deal with the server, not in the front end. But this moment I can't do anything in the back-end, I have to
figure out a way from front-end. Is there any way to over come this error.

Or else do you guys know any other library works well with URLS as pdf sources?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loading cross-domain endpoint with jQuery AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15005500/loading-cross-domain-endpoint-with-jquery-ajax). Ignore that the question is asking about jQuery and focus on the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17299796/283366)

Comment: Did you fixed ?

Answer (score 0):

add "mode" no-cors in your request.

```
pdf.createLoadingTask({
                        url: 'www.example.com',
                        withCredentials: false,
                        httpHeaders: {
                            "mode": "no-cors",
                            "cache": "no-cache",
                        },
                    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use CORS Proxy Servers to solve browser CORS problems.

On this case, you have 2 options:
1°) Creating your own server. There are repositories available on GitHub with the necessary code, allowing you to clone the repository and set up your server. For instance, you can check out this repository for a ready-to-use solution: https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere.
Creating your own server is more secure since you have control over your server's maintenance and uptime.

Or
2°) Alternatively, there are free proxy servers already in operation that you can use. CorsProxy.io is one such service. It provides a straightforward and free proxy to bypass CORS errors. To use this service, prepend the proxy URL https://corsproxy.io/? before the destination URL. The service will then make the request to the URL with the correct CORS headers on your behalf.

For your specific case, here's how you could modify your Vue.js component:

```
<template>
  <pdf :src="proxyUrl + encodeURIComponent('https://lovezwl.vip/pdf.pdf')"></pdf>
</template>

<script>
import pdf from 'vue-pdf'

export default {
  components: {
    pdf
  },
  computed: {
    proxyUrl() {
      return 'https://corsproxy.io/?';
    }
  }
}
```

Remember that relying on external CORS proxies for production environments is not recommended due to stability and security concerns. It's better to manage CORS on your server or use a trusted, secure proxy service.

Answer (score -1):

`vue-pdf` internally uses XMLHttpRequest. You need to configure the server where your PDF is located (lovezwl.vip) to send CORS headers to allow your local server (localhost) to fetch your document. At the very least send a header like:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"
```

Of course you can set a more restrictive header which better fits your case.

If you are not in control of the server and can not change the configuration then you can't embed this PDF file using vue-pdf.

Comment: OP says _"this moment I **can't do anything in the back-end**, I have to figure out a way from front-end"_. Also, this can be solved by using a proxy as outlined in the linked duplicate so it's incorrect to say that it cannot be done