# Ajax Call 200 OK but console.log is not returning the correct result

Tags: jquery, ajax, api

I hope you can help me with this. I am really new to API.

I created an Ajax call and it is returning 200 OK but on my "complete" function, it is returning this

[image]

instead of the data. But when i checked the "network" the response has the data i need.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
 $(function () {
  $.ajax({
   url: "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://crm.com/api/v1/PurchaseOrders",
   headers: { "Authorization": "Basic Uxxxxxxxxxxx2U1OTMzOGQwMTY3M2QzM2M5OQ==" },
   method: 'GET',
   dataType: 'json',
   complete: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    },
   success: function (json) {
    console.log('success');
    console.log(json);
   },
   error: function (error) {
    console.log('error');
    console.log(error);
   }
  });
 })
```

Please note that i also tried success and error function but still same.

PS: When i removed dataType jsonp, an error 405 Method not allowed is returning

Also, when the dataType is jsonp, then i refresh the page where i put this code, there's a prompt asking for credentials.

Edit: This code now returning error 500.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203077/discussion-on-question-by-noob-dev-ajax-call-200-ok-but-console-log-is-not-retur).

Comment: Try to add contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', in ajax.This may help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loading cross-domain endpoint with jQuery AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15005500/loading-cross-domain-endpoint-with-jquery-ajax)